# How to find a function in similar shape but strictly greater than $f(x)\sim ce^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ by a little?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory, numerical-methods

How to find a function in similar shape but strictly greater than $f(x)\sim ce^{-\frac{x^2}{2}},c>0$ by a little? We have to keep $f(x)$ being integrable so we can't shift the intercept. The function $f$ is proved to be symmetric, positive, and decaying as above. $f(x)$ comes from the differential equation $$\frac{1}{2}f''+\frac{x}{2}f'+f-\frac{1}{2}f^2=0,f'(0)=0,f(0)=1.40$$

I don't need an exact answer but I need a procedure so that I can follow

I tried gaussian interplant $(ax+b)e^{-cx^2}$ or $a_1e^{-b_1x^2}+a_2xe^{-b_2x^2}$ but the fitted curves are always beaten by the data when $x$ gets large.

Comment: @LutzL sorry actually only the function's asymptotic behaviour is known

Comment: @LutzL can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Set $u(t)=F(Nt)$, $N$ large, to zoom out to see the behavior at large $x=Nt$. Then 
$$
u''+N^2(tu'+2u-u^2)=0
$$
can be seen as a perturbation of the first order equation
$$
tu'+2u-u^2=0\iff \frac1t=\frac{u'}{u(u-2)}=\frac12(\frac{u'}{u-2}-\frac{u'}{u})
$$
leading to 
$$
Ct^2=\frac{2-u}u\iff u=\frac{2}{1+Ct^2}
$$
which then translates to $F(x)\simeq \dfrac2{1+Cx^2}$ for $x\gg0$.

---

For your solution, I found a good (graphical/visual) fit with $C=26.1965$.